# Ubuntu software center does not show screenshot previews after fresh install of 17.04

Tags: screenshot

excuse the two questions in such a short time.
I installed the latest ubuntu version (no upgrade, full installation)
and since that the screenshots for apps on the app store don't show up.
Any help is appreciated.
(The screenshots showed fine in the previous version of ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

First, try the following commands and see if the problem is fixed:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Launch the Software Center and check, if the problem still persists:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

This should solve the problem.

If it still doesn't fix the problem, the following should solve the problem:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo apt-get autoremove gnome-software
sudo apt-get install gnome-software
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, none of the steps suggested here resolves the problem.